# VSCode remote development server prerequisites on HPC server managed via environment modules

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, environment-modules

I have installed the VSCode remote development extension pack, and I am trying to connect to the remote host via the `Remote-SSH: Connect to Host` command, however it fails to automatically install the code server with the message:

```
The remote host may not meet VS Code Server's prerequisites for glibc and libstdc++
```

Now it may just be the case that the versions of these are too old on the server, however what I suspect is more likely is that I just need to run some appropriate `module load XXX` commands on the server to put that sort of thing on the PATH before VSCode tries to install the server. I.e. the server is a HPC machine with environments managed by environment modules.

Is there some way to tell VSCode to run extra commands like this before it tries to install or run the code server? I guess there might be some way to manually install the code server (if so how?) but it probably still will not launch correctly when needed since glibc and libstdc++ still won't be on the path unless I can inject these `module load` commands. Though I wonder if this will cause other hassles during development, since I need to develop with various different modules loaded depending on what I am working on.

Edit: perhaps I can add some commands to be run automatically to my .ssh/config file, haven't tried that yet...

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the remote server had the storage full.

Answer (score 2):

This problem might occur when the disk space in remote machine is full.
Check the disk space in remote machine using command

```
df -h
```

if found use% greater than 90. Try to remove some un-necessary files

Answer (score 1):

I remove the dir ".vscode-server" in linux, and reinstall the vs plugin, then reconnect the remote host

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that for some reason the whole storage (USB stick) on my remote raspberry pi was suddenly 'write protected'. After reboot and change to other USB-slot, VSC worked fine again.